# How to post image to custom field of my custom post type when it returns data:image\/jpeg;base64 string through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I implemented my custom form and I need to post Image to custom field of my Custom Post Type, but it did not worked, cause image returns long string in base64 encoding...

javascript, ajax:

```
// get values to an array()


     var requestArray = "";

        requestArray = {"name" : $("#nameAdvertisement").val(),
        "category" : $("#categoryAdvertisement").val(),
        "description" : $("#descriptionAdvertisement").val(),
        "photo" : $("#photoAdvertisement").val(),
        "photoAdvertisement" : $("#pro-img-4").attr('src')};


        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: {"action": "addAdvertisement", "formValidation": requestArray},
            //dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {


            }
        });
```

functions.php, where code is incoming for posting my data ( `$getData['photoAdvertisement']` represents long image string)

```
$getData = $_POST['formValidation'];

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => 'New Posts with Image',
        'post_content'  => 'Some testing content',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_type' => 'inzeraty'
    );

// Insert the post into the database
   $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post);

    add_post_meta($post_id, 'name', 'Name of New post', true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'description', 'Description of new Post', true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'photo', $getData['photoAdvertisement'], true);
```

Comment: My guess is, that you will need to move the file to the library, and then add the new image ID to the meta field.

Comment: @Stender and do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Tried to explain the process to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This will need to be tweaked -

This works with URls of images, but not sure how you will get the `$image_data` through post.

First, you will need to decode the base64 image.

```
$newImageFile = base64_decode($getData['photoAdvertisement']);
```

Then you will need to find the directories to work with :

```
 $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
 $image_data = file_get_contents($newImageFile);
 $filename = basename($newImageFile);
```

Now that you have a filename, you can check if the file and the filename already exists in your library

```
if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
        else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
        file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
        $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
```

You will need the functionalities of post.php - so if you don't have it yet, then include it.

```
        if ( ! function_exists( 'post_exists' ) ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
        }
```

this way you can check, if the same filename has already been used in your library like this

```
if (post_exists($filename)){
    //Do whatever - maybe update the alt or something. 
}else {
    //The file does not exist, and can be inserted.
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id ); 
    // $post_id comes from your earlier insertion
    // You will need the functions from image.php as well.. 
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    //Now we will generate the new image metadata
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $filealt = "You alternative text here - maybe sanitize the filename or make an input for it";

    //attach the metadata to the image
    update_post_meta($attach_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $filealt); // Add the alt text

    //Now you can add the image to your meta fields
     add_post_meta($post_id, 'photo', $attach_id);

}
```

Note, I have not tested this.

You will probably need to tweak it a little - Especially around the `file_get_contents($newImageFile);` part.

**NOTE** : This has to be done **after** your `$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post);` part

Good luck with it!

Comment: thank you so much, will try that definitely, but it does not matter that I upload a picture from the desktop ?